# Limit total CPU core docker can allocate

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I am using docker/K8s to deploy some pods.

Now, I need to limit total CPU that worker can use for running container (not limit CPU for each Container).

For example: we have 24 cores Linux Server. But I want to only use 20 cores for docker runtime.

Could we do that?

Comment: Kubernetes's typical assumption is that it has absolute control over the nodes it runs; frequently a tool like the cluster autoscaler will create or destroy nodes outside your direct control.  What do you want to do with this reserved capacity, and how reserved do you want it?  (Do you just want to limit resource requests to 80% of the node capacity, or limit actual utilization, or reserve cores?)

Comment: Because in same that worker server, we have some other agent (antivirus, monitor ..) could take CPU, so I need to limit a mount of CPU (not all CPU core) for docker runtime.

Comment: Just run those processes (maybe via Kubernetes DaemonSets) and the host kernel will take care of assigning CPU slices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to look into [Kubelet configuration parameters](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kubelet-config.v1beta1/). There are parameters like `systemReserved`, `reservedSystemCPUs` and others which may help you to accomplish what you need.

In the past these were [Kubelet options](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kubelet/), but these are now deprecating in favour of a config file.

Comment: Thank you for your suggest, I will try

Comment: Base on your suggest, we was apply some config like this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/reserve-compute-resources/  and now I can see total CPU resource can be allocate on Rancher has been decrease.  Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can limit the resources for docker in your OS:

1. Create the file `/etc/systemd/system/docker_limit.slice` with the following content

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Slice that limits docker resources
   Before=slices.target

   [Slice]
   CPUAccounting=true
   CPUQuota=2000%
   ```
2. Start unit: `systemctl start docker_limit.slice`
3. Edit `/etc/docker/daemon.json`

   ```
   {
     "cgroup-parent": "/docker_limit.slice"
   }
   ```
4. Restart Docker daemon: `systemctl restart docker`

credits to [@Leletir](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/550954/295368)

**Hint:**
we take a quota of `2000%`, because the `CPUQuota` relates to **one** CPU (in your case 20 CPUs * 100%):

> CPUQuota=
>
> Assign the specified CPU time quota to the processes executed. Takes a
> percentage value, suffixed with "%". The percentage specifies how much
> CPU time the unit shall get at maximum, relative to the total CPU time
> available on one CPU. **Use values > 100% for allotting CPU time on more
> than one CPU.** This controls the "cpu.max" attribute on the unified
> control group hierarchy and "cpu.cfs_quota_us" on legacy. For details
> about these control group attributes, see Control Groups v2 and
> sched-bwc.txt.
>
> Example: CPUQuota=20% ensures that the executed processes will never
> get more than 20% CPU time on one CPU.

you can get more details about the parameters from the man page of `systemd.resource-control`:

```
$ man systemd.resource-control
```

or on https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html

Comment: Could we config CPU core instead of percent ?, I will try your solution and let you know result.

Comment: Hi @user3611168 from the man page (`man systemd.resource-control`) it says that it only accepts percentage values (`Assign the specified CPU time quota to the processes executed. Takes a percentage value, suffixed with "%". The percentage specifies how much CPU time the unit shall get at maximum, relative to the total CPU time available on one CPU. Use values > 100% for allotting CPU time on more than one CPU.`)

Answer (score 1):

Each container’s access to the host machine’s CPU cycles is unlimited. You can set various constraints to `limit` a given container’s access to the host machine’s CPU cycles, k8s uses kernel throttling to implement CPU limit. ( a container is not allowed to use more than its resource `limit` e.g. CPU represents compute processing and is specified in units of [Kubernetes CPUs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#meaning-of-cpu)

`cgroups` are being used  to control CPU scheduling and isolate CPU usage at the container level, the  kubelet uses CFS quota mechanism to enforce pod CPU limits you can set the  --`cpu-manager-policy` kubelet option, take a look at this answer: [Changing the CPU Manager Policy in Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54227755/changing-the-cpu-manager-policy-in-kubernetes)

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/cpu-management-policies/#configuration

As a side note, usually at the host level you can try to configure CFS scheduler or the realtime scheduler

https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#configure-the-default-cfs-scheduler
https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/#configure-the-realtime-scheduler